# Proportional Circles QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-3

In QGIS 3 there is the possibility to illustrate proportional data like population with circle of proportional size with the "assistant" option.

But once in the print composer section, there is an empty symbol in the legend. 
How to show 2 or 3 circles of proportional size in the legend?

Comment: Instead of using the size assistant, use graduated symbology with *Method: Size*. Then the legend will show the different point sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but in this case the circles are not proportional. They are classified only in a few size and categories.

Comment: My problem with the same thing is, that once i add the proportional Symbols the Legendsymbols are missing. I can have the legendentry for the different sizes, but the colours which I did for the different classes are missing.

Answer (score 7):

I've found a working solution within QGIS3:

It works with a point layer

- Symbology = simple marker
- Size proportional to a field thanks to the "assistant" tool (click on
  the data defined override button)

Then go back to the general "Marker" option on the Symbology tree and at the bottom go to the "advanced" button option then "Data defined size legend".

You will be able to make a nice legend with proportionnal circle symbol

Comment: Hi Arthur, I used your recommended steps in trying to solve this issue and each time, I get "Data-defined size is not enabled!" despite doing that using the "assistant" feature.

PS: I am using QGIS3

Comment: Now works on the print composer despite still getting that message. Thanks!